# Zend Session 2 common cookie domains

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, session, subdomain

I have 3 domains:

```
example.com
m.example.com
dev.example.com
```

Session should be common for `example.com` and `m.example.com`. How I have made it.
Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initSession()
{
        Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
            'cookie_domain' => '.example.com',
            'name'          => 'ExampleSession'
        ));
        Zend_Session::start();
}
```

But this session works for `dev.example.com` too. How I can avoid common session for `dev.example.com`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well the only way I see to make this possible is to dynamically set the cookie domain depending on the hostname.

it could look something like this:

```
protected function _initSession()
{
        Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
            'cookie_domain' => ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'dev.example.com' ? 'dev.example.com' : '.example.com'),
            'name'          => 'ExampleSession'
        ));
        Zend_Session::start();
}
```